# What could cause 1996 Volkswagen Golf Chico loss of electrical power?

Tags: vw

My golf cuts out when I switch on the head lights but it doesn't die. It will cut and all the dash lights will go but it will coast start again and go. This only happens sometimes.

When I tap the brake, the lights will dim or I will hear a distortion on the radio. Even when I put an indicator on, the main lights will flick too. This happens now more often but still doesn't continuously happen. Once it cut out and wouldn't get power for almost an hour. I had to jump start it with another car before the main power relay kicked in and I had power on the cluster again.

What can it be?

Comment: sounds to me like a bad ground.

Comment: I cleaned all the ground connections and even stripped the paint where it was touching the ground.

Comment: Or a bad alternator/battery system.  I would measure battery voltage while this condition occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the battery is fully charged.  It may be early signs of a failing battery or that alternator may not be providing sufficient charge.